# WPF window template resource

Tags: resources, templates, wpf-controls, window

I am trying to define a window template that can be used by windows in other assemblies. I define a window template and store it in resource dictionary in some assembly. After, I use this template in other assembly on window definition in XAML. It looks that the template is accepted and I can see updated window in VS-2010 designer but when I add a new control to this window, the control disappears from window but still exists in XAML code. I also tried to apply the same template explicitly and it works well.

Xaml code of generic.xaml in project that contains template definition, the ThemeInfo attribute is set and BuildAction property for this file is Page.

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly= {x:Type local:DialogResources}, ResourceId=DialogTemplate}">  
  <Border Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="windowFrame"  
       BorderBrush="#395984"
       BorderThickness="1"
       CornerRadius="0,20,20,20" 
       Background="AliceBlue">

    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Margin="1" Padding="5" Text="Template Window" FontWeight="Bold"/>

      <Border Background="#B5CBEF" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="0,0,20,20" >
        <AdornerDecorator>
          <ContentPresenter/>
        </AdornerDecorator>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

DialogRespources - is an empty class that defined in MyProg.Resources assembly.
Now I use this template in other assembly like this:

In this window I add a button but I can't to see it. When I define the TemplateControl explicitly (without using resource) I can see it.

The other problem is that I get a following designer exception when use TargetType="{x:Type Window}" for template in resource: "'Window' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'WindowInstance'." I could not find anything regarding this exception in Google.

Please, help me to understand what is wrong in my code?